# Calling functions with maps using @

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I've come across some syntax that I cannot understand. Here is a sample

```
$someList = @( <# ... #> )

$name = "someString"

$myMap = @{
   Name = $name
   Foo = 15
}

Invoke-MyFoo @myMap @someList
```

What is the meaning `@`-signs in the `Invoke-MyFoo` expression? What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a technique known as [splatting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx).  It lets you pass a set of parameters as a hashtable or array instead of specifying them all with the cmdlet.

If you're asking a more basic question, then `@( )` identifies an [array](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847882.aspx), and `@{ }` identifies a [hashtable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847780.aspx).

Comment: Well that was quick! Thank you!